# A conjecture for an inequality for every odd number.

Tags: inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers

Let $E(n) = \sum_{d|n} d \log(d) $. Then for coprime $n,m$ we have $$E(mn) = \sigma(m) E(n) + \sigma(n) E(m).$$ Suppose there exists an odd perfect number $n$. Then$$E(2n) = E(2)\sigma(n)+E(n)\sigma(2) = 4 n \log(2) + 3 E(n).$$ But looking at a few numerical examples, one can see that the right hand side seems to be alway bigger than the left hand side. Consider [the upper bound for logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Upper_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm):$$\log(x) \le x^s/s. \quad \forall s>0$$ Making use of this upper bound we can derive:
$$E(2n) = 2 \sum_{d|n} d \log(2d) + E(n) \le 2 \sum_{d|n} \frac{(2d)^s}{s} + E(n). \quad \forall s > 0$$ Now the question is, how do we choose $s>0$ such that we have $$2 \sum_{d|n} \frac{(2d)^s}{s} + E(n) < 4 n \log(2) + 3 E(n).$$
My conjecture is, that it is always possible to choose one such $s>0$ such that the last inequality is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $E(2n) = 2\sigma(n)\log 2+3E(n)$ holds for any odd $n$.

You're trying to show that it is always less than $4n\log 2+3E(n)$, i.e. that all odd numbers are "deficient" (i.e. $\sigma(n) < 2n$).

This is not true, there are "abundant" ($\sigma(n) > 2n$) odd numbers as well.

---

You'd have to exploit further the assumption that $n$ is perfect for this method to work.

Comment: Can you give an example $n$?

Comment: See [OEIS A005101](https://oeis.org/A005101): 12, 18, 20, ..., **945**, ...

Comment: Thank you, I also checked numerically, that with 945 my argument does not work.